# Can I free permissions on a USB drive?

Tags: usb, permissions, kubuntu

I need a simple way to change permissions so that anyone can read and write anywhere on the drive. If it can be done without the terminal, so much the better!

Long version:
3 years ago I bought a BuffaloHD-PXTU2 1 terabyte USB drive for archiving. At the time my wife and I both had Windows XP, but we wrote to the drive directly rather than using the Buffalo Windows Utility provided.

2 years ago I installed Kubuntu 12.04 on my computer, though still use XP occasionally. Still no problems copying.

A year ago my wife's computer blew up and she bought a pretty iMac. I cannot get the Mac to write to the Buffalo drive, though it will read. I believe the problem is that Kubuntu has at some stage taken over and hijacked the permissions, though I can still write with XP.

In fact, after my wife's computer blew up, I copied data from her hard drive to the Buffalo drive and thence later to the new Mac. Whatever the cause, I need a simple way to change permissions so that anyone can read and write anywhere on the drive. If it can be done without the terminal, so much the better!

Comment: If the Mac is using Mac OSX then this is a problem with Mac OSX and you should ask this question on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you write a short version for those who don't care about history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a formating issue. Mac's aren't equipped to write to NTFS, and with a drive of that type it could easily be formatted as NTFS.

1) Backup the entire drive. You should be able to drag and drop all of the contents to a desktop folder.
2) Go to launchpad, and then search for 'Disk Utility' 
3) Find your drive. You should be able to find it by space. 
4) Click 'erase'. This formats your drive into something Mac can read.
5) When it's done, put all of your files back.

One of the things I don't understand is that Linux and Windows can both read and write to NTFS, but for some strange reason this doesn't work. You should be able to still write on a Linux platform, but I understand that it may be convenient for getting files back and forth.

Comment: Thanks Mike whatever for rewriting my question in a more logical order. I'm sorry about the history, but I don't know what info is needed by anyone kind enough to help me. Thanx Ilarsona, the drive is indeed NTFS which explains why the Mac will read and not write. I will get another drive for the Mac as space is short. I'd still like to know how to make any folder or device fully accessible to all in Linux.